# TikZ diagram: how to make arrow like this

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

How can i make arrows like this?

[image: arrow diagram]

This is what I've done so far.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[left=22mm,bottom=22mm,right=28mm,top=30mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

% Define block styles
\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, draw, fill=blue!20, 
    text width=4.5em, text badly centered, node distance=3cm, inner sep=0pt]
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, 
    text width=2cm, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=10mm]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']
\tikzstyle{cloud} = [draw, ellipse,fill=red!20, node distance=3cm,
    minimum height=2em]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 3.4cm, auto]

 \node  [block,yshift=30mm] (1) {1};
      \node [block, xshift=-30mm] (2) {2};
      \node[block, xshift=-60mm] (3) {3};
\node [block, xshift=-90mm] (4) {4};
        \node [block, xshift=-120mm] (5) {5};

       \node [block,yshift=30mm, xshift=-45mm] (6) {6};
         \node [block,yshift=-40mm, xshift=-105mm] (7) {7};
     \node [block,yshift=-60mm, xshift=-105mm] (8) {8};
             \node [block,yshift=-25mm, xshift=-75mm] (9) {9};
\node[block, xshift=-60mm,yshift=-60mm] (10) {10};
\node [block, xshift=-30mm,yshift=-60mm] (11) {11};
\node[block, xshift=0mm,yshift=-60mm] (12) {12};

\draw[->,>=latex'] (4) -- (3);
\draw[->,>=latex'] (3) -- (2);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image: my attempt]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! To highlight code-blocks, either indent them by four spaces or use the `{}` on the gui. Also, please don't post external links as they may not be available in, say, a years time. It is much better if you include the image directly in your post.

Comment: One trick is to use \draw (9) -| (7);  Another is to locate a corner using \coordinate (97) at (9 -| 7);

Comment: Why did you delete everything in both your question and my answer?

Comment: That's ridiculous. Why ever not? You may be able to delete it. I'm not sure. But it will still be there. Deleted posts are still on the site. Why did you post on a public website if you didn't want it here? This is how the site works: your question stays for other users.

Comment: I've flagged this for the mods to rollback.

Comment: What do you mean? I said it is public - nothing about its being popular. What difference does that make?

Comment: What good would it do there? People search questions and answers - not profiles. Don't be silly.

Comment: If the problem is the image in your question, can you replace it? It won't delete the image, because you've posted that elsewhere by uploading it, but it might make it less visible. Not sure whether that would help. What is on the web publicly is there forever, except when somebody wants to find something again.

Comment: If there is an issue here with confidential information, please flag and the mod team will look at it. We can remove such items form the entire history if required.

Answer (score 10):

A bit of a miscellany ...

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,x11names,svgnames,dvipsnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,shadows.blur}% arrows is deprecated ; shapes would be better loaded with the required suffixes
\begin{document}
\tikzset{% \tikzstyle is deprecated
  block/.style={draw, top color=white!90!#1, bottom color=#1, shading angle=45, text width=2cm, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=10mm},
}
\begin{tikzpicture} [node distance = 3.4cm, >=Latex, thick, draw=darkgray, every node/.append style={blur shadow}]
  \node [block=Crimson, text=white, yshift=30mm] (1) {1};
  \node [block=gray!40, xshift=-30mm] (2) {2};
  \node [block=green!25, xshift=-60mm] (3) {3};
  \node [block=magenta!25, xshift=-90mm] (4) {4};
  \node [block=yellow!30, xshift=-120mm] (5) {5};

  \node [block=DodgerBlue3, text=white, yshift=30mm, xshift=-45mm] (6) {6};
  \node [block=yellow!30, yshift=-40mm, xshift=-105mm] (7) {7};
  \node [block=magenta!25, yshift=-60mm, xshift=-105mm] (8) {8};
  \node [block=DodgerBlue3, text=white, yshift=-25mm, xshift=-75mm] (9) {9};
  \node [block=green!25, xshift=-60mm,yshift=-60mm] (10) {10};
  \node [block=Purple3!75!Periwinkle, text=white, xshift=-30mm,yshift=-60mm] (11) {11};
  \node [block=green!25, xshift=0mm,yshift=-60mm] (12) {12};

  \begin{scope}[every node/.append style={circle, draw=darkgray, anchor=center, fill=white, inner sep=1pt}, draw=darkgray, every edge/.append style={->, draw}]
    \path
    (5) edge coordinate [pos=.4] (a) (4)
    (4) edge coordinate [pos=.4] (b) (3)
    (3) edge coordinate [pos=.4] (c) (2)
    (a) edge (7)
    (12) edge (11)
    (11) edge (10)
    (10) edge coordinate [pos=.2] (d)  (8)
    (8) edge (7)
    (d) edge (9.south -| d)
    (b) edge (9.north -| b)
    (c) edge (6.south -| c)
    (2) -- (2 -| 1) coordinate [pos=.2] (e) node [pos=1, anchor=center] (f) {+}
    ;
    \path [every edge/.append style={<-}]
    (f) edge (1) edge (2);
    \path (12) edge (f);
    \draw [->] (e) |- (6);
    \draw [->] (e) |- (9);
    \foreach \i in {a,...,e} \node at (\i) {};
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: connecting dots and shading blocks]