# Drawing a scheme

Tags: lyx, diagrams

I am writing my assignment in LyX. I am very new to this program, but I would like to create a scheme similar to this:

[image: Shceme]

Is this possible to do? Does anyone have templates similar to this one?
I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Welcome to LaTeX! [Welcome to TeX.SX](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document. A pointer: try the `tikz` package

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. There are many ways to do that, for example with a `tikz matrix`.  See here: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/feature/matrices/ also on this site you could find several examples, like: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/370306/101651. Please try to do something by yourself and, if you have any problem, add an MWE to your question.

Comment: Try searching this this site for e.g. flowchart or organization chart, or see Texample.net (http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/simple-flow-chart/). In LyX you'll need to write the TikZ code (if you choose to use TikZ) in a TeX code inset (aka ERT).

Comment: To the downvoters: one downvote is even too much, let's give the OP time for updating his question! Idem for the ready-to-close ones...

Comment: Consider using dia. See here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/367703/12212

Answer (score 6):

You could use `tikz` directly in LyX.

Choose `Document --> Settings --> LaTeX preamble` and add these two lines:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shapes}
```

Then, in your document - within a `figure` environment (since I wrote `\centering` it should be put within a group), or a `center` environment directly (without `\centering`) or any other similar way you like - put the following code in an `ERT` (pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> or the specific icon or via menu `Insert --> TeX code`). Note that when pasting code into an `ERT` you must use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> (`Edit -> Paste special`) to preserve line breaks.

```
\centering\noindent%
\begin{tikzpicture}[        
    ellipsenode/.style={
        ellipse, 
        fill=orange,
        inner sep=4pt,
        text width=5em, 
        text=white,
        text centered
    },
    rectnode/.style={
        rounded corners, 
        fill=#1,
        inner sep=10pt,
        text=white,
        text width=7em, 
        text centered
    },
    graynode/.style={
        draw=gray,
        very thick,
        inner sep=4pt,
        text=gray,
        text centered
    },
    myline/.style={
        draw=#1,
        line width=1.5pt,
    },
    ]
    \matrix[
        matrix of nodes,            
        column sep=1.2em, 
        row sep=4ex, 
        row 1/.style={nodes={ellipsenode}},
        row 2/.style={nodes={rectnode={black}}},
        row 3/.style={nodes={graynode}},
        row 4/.style={nodes={rectnode={black}}},
        row 5/.style={nodes={rectnode={orange}}},
    ] (m) {
    {\textbf{Investor} \\ \textit{\small(LP)}} & {\textbf{Investor} \\ \textit{\small(LP)}} & {\textbf{Investor} \\ \textit{\small(LP)}} \\                 
    & {\textbf{General} \\ \textbf{Partner} \textit{\small(GP)}} \\
    & Limited Partner Agreement \\
    & {\textbf{Limited} \\ \textbf{Liability}\\ \textbf{Partnership}\\ \textit{\small(LLP)}} \\
    {\textbf{Portfolio} \\ \textbf{Companies}} & {\textbf{Portfolio} \\ \textbf{Companies}} & {\textbf{Portfolio} \\ \textbf{Companies}} \\             
    };  
    \draw[myline=orange] (m-1-1.south) |- (m-4-2)
        (m-1-2.west) -- ++(-3em,0) |- (m-4-2.165)
        (m-1-3.south) |- (m-4-2)
        (m-4-2.south) -- (m-5-2)
        (m-4-2.south) -- ++(0,-2ex) -| (m-5-1)
        (m-4-2.south) -- ++(0,-2ex) -| (m-5-3)
    ;
    \draw[myline=gray, dashed] (m-1-1.-45) |- (m-2-2)
        (m-1-2) -- (m-2-2)
        (m-1-3.-135) |- (m-2-2)
    ;
    \draw[myline=orange, dashed] (m-2-2) -- (m-3-2) -- (m-4-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

After running and this is the result:

[image]

This is the complete code you could save with a `.lyx` extension and open directly in LyX:

```
#LyX 2.2 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 508
\begin_document
\begin_header
\save_transient_properties true
\origin unavailable
\textclass article
\begin_preamble
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shapes}
\end_preamble
\use_default_options true
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language english
\language_package default
\inputencoding auto
\fontencoding global
\font_roman "default" "default"
\font_sans "default" "default"
\font_typewriter "default" "default"
\font_math "auto" "auto"
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100 100
\font_tt_scale 100 100
\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize default
\spacing single
\use_hyperref false
\papersize default
\use_geometry false
\use_package amsmath 1
\use_package amssymb 1
\use_package cancel 1
\use_package esint 1
\use_package mathdots 1
\use_package mathtools 1
\use_package mhchem 1
\use_package stackrel 1
\use_package stmaryrd 1
\use_package undertilde 1
\cite_engine basic
\cite_engine_type default
\biblio_style plain
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\justification true
\use_refstyle 1
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\quotes_language english
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset Float figure
wide false
sideways false
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout
\begin_inset ERT
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
centering
\backslash
noindent%
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
begin{tikzpicture}[         
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

    ellipsenode/.style={
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

        ellipse, 
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

        fill=orange,
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

        inner sep=4pt,
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

        text width=5em, 
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

        text=white,
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

        text centered
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

    },
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

    rectnode/.style={
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

        rounded corners, 
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

        fill=#1,
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

        inner sep=10pt,
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

        text=white,
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

        text width=7em, 
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

        text centered
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

    },
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

    graynode/.style={
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

        draw=gray,
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

        very thick,
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

        inner sep=4pt,
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

        text=gray,
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

        text centered
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

    },
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

    myline/.style={
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

        draw=#1,
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

        line width=1.5pt,
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

    },
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

    ]
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
matrix[
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

        matrix of nodes,            
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

        column sep=1.2em, 
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

        row sep=4ex, 
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

        row 1/.style={nodes={ellipsenode}},
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

        row 2/.style={nodes={rectnode={black}}},
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

        row 3/.style={nodes={graynode}},
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

        row 4/.style={nodes={rectnode={black}}},
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

        row 5/.style={nodes={rectnode={orange}}},
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

    ] (m) {
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

    {
\backslash
textbf{Investor} 
\backslash

\backslash

\backslash
textit{
\backslash
small(LP)}} & {
\backslash
textbf{Investor} 
\backslash

\backslash

\backslash
textit{
\backslash
small(LP)}} & {
\backslash
textbf{Investor} 
\backslash

\backslash

\backslash
textit{
\backslash
small(LP)}} 
\backslash

\backslash

\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

    & {
\backslash
textbf{General} 
\backslash

\backslash

\backslash
textbf{Partner} 
\backslash
textit{
\backslash
small(GP)}} 
\backslash

\backslash

\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

    & Limited Partner Agreement 
\backslash

\backslash

\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

    & {
\backslash
textbf{Limited} 
\backslash

\backslash

\backslash
textbf{Liability}
\backslash

\backslash

\backslash
textbf{Partnership}
\backslash

\backslash

\backslash
textit{
\backslash
small(LLP)}} 
\backslash

\backslash

\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

    {
\backslash
textbf{Portfolio} 
\backslash

\backslash

\backslash
textbf{Companies}} & {
\backslash
textbf{Portfolio} 
\backslash

\backslash

\backslash
textbf{Companies}} & {
\backslash
textbf{Portfolio} 
\backslash

\backslash

\backslash
textbf{Companies}} 
\backslash

\backslash

\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

    };  
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
draw[myline=orange] (m-1-1.south) |- (m-4-2)
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

        (m-1-2.west) -- ++(-3em,0) |- (m-4-2.165)
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

        (m-1-3.south) |- (m-4-2)
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

        (m-4-2.south) -- (m-5-2)
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

        (m-4-2.south) -- ++(0,-2ex) -| (m-5-1)
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

        (m-4-2.south) -- ++(0,-2ex) -| (m-5-3)
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

    ;
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
draw[myline=gray, dashed] (m-1-1.-45) |- (m-2-2)
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

        (m-1-2) -- (m-2-2)
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

        (m-1-3.-135) |- (m-2-2)
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

    ;
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
draw[myline=orange, dashed] (m-2-2) -- (m-3-2) -- (m-4-2);
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
end{tikzpicture}
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout
\begin_inset Caption Standard

\begin_layout Plain Layout
My figure
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

Comment: (+1) I took the liberty of adding a small note about pasting into ERTs. I didn't remove the `\centering`, though it might perhaps be better to place it in a group, or remove it, so that the rest of the document isn't centered as well ...

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thank you for the editing. In my example it is within a `figure` enrivonrment (see the .lyx file), however I'll add a note.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Note added, hoping it's clear :):):)

Comment: Oh, right, sorry about that. Didn't notice the `figure`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. It's very difficult to notice something in a LyX code LOL! Do they really write `\begin_layout Plain Layout ...
\end_layout` for _every_ line of ERT? OMG!

Comment: Well, the format of the `.lyx` file isn't really relevant for users, it's auto generated after all, and should be easily parsed by computers, not humans.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Now I understand why it is so long! :)